Getting error in TensorFlowJS RNN example in TypeScript
I am trying to create a minimal RNN TensorFlowJS example in TypeScript, but I can't seem to get the tensor shapes right.  The goal is to take two hard coded melodies and predict a new melody.  I am totally new to TensorFlow and machine learning, and just want a working example to build on and learn from.  Thanks.
Here is the code:
  shiftMelody(melody:number[][]):number[][] {
    var result:number[][] = [];
    var oneNote:number[];

    for (var i = 0; i < melody.length; ++ i) {
      if (i < (melody.length - 1)) {
        oneNote = melody[i+1];
      } else {
        oneNote = melody[i];  //when we reach the end, just repeast same last note
      }
      result.push(oneNote);
    }
    return result;

  }

  public generateMelody() {

    // Example melodies as series of notes.  Note is [note number, timestamp]
    let melody1 = [[60,0], [62,1], [64,2], [65,3], [67,4], [69,5], [71,6], [72,7]];
    let melody2 = [[60,0], [62,1], [64,2], [70,3], [80,4], [85,5], [90,6], [95,7]];

    // Combine melodies and convert to tensors
    let melodies = [melody1, melody2];
    let xs = tf.tensor3d(melodies);

    // Targets are the next note in each melody
    const targets1 = this.shiftMelody(melody1);
    const targets2 = this.shiftMelody(melody2);

    let targets = [targets1, targets2];
    let ys = tf.tensor3d(targets);

    // Define the model
    let model = tf.sequential();

    model.add(tf.layers.lstm({
      units: 100,
      returnSequences: false,
      inputShape: [xs.shape[1], 1],
    }));

    model.add(tf.layers.dense({
      units: ys.shape[1],
      activation: 'softmax',
    }));

    // Compile the model
    model.compile({
      optimizer: 'adam',
      loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy',
      metrics: ['accuracy'],
    });

    // Train the model
    model.fit(xs, ys, {
      epochs: 100,
      callbacks: {
        onEpochEnd: (epoch, logs) => {
          console.log(`Epoch ${epoch}: loss = ${logs!['loss']}`);
        },
      },
    });

    // Predict a new melody
    let newMelody = [[60,0], [62,1], [64,2], [65,3], [67,4], [69,5], [71,6], [72,7]];
    let input = tf.tensor2d(newMelody);

    let prediction = model.predict(input);

    console.log(`Prediction: ${prediction}`);
  }

But I'm getting the following errors:
tflow.service.ts:63  Orthogonal initializer is being called on a matrix with more than 2000 (40000) elements: Slowness may result.

ERROR Error: Error when checking : expected lstm_LSTM1_input to have 3 dimension(s), but got array with shape [8,2]
    at checkInputData (training.js:283:23)
    at LayersModel.predict (training.js:896:9)
    at _Sequential.predict (models.js:653:27)
    at _TflowService.generateMelody (tflow.service.ts:95:28)
    at _TensorflowComponent.doTest10 (tensorflow.component.ts:575:23)
    at TensorflowComponent_Template_button_click_29_listener (tensorflow.component.html:22:18)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.mjs:26043:16)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.mjs:26076:22)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.mjs:749:112)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:403:31)
Zone - HTMLButtonElement.addEventListener:click (async)     
TensorflowComponent_Template    @   tensorflow.component.html:22


core.mjs:7473  ERROR Error: input expected a batch of elements where each example has shape [8,1] (i.e.,tensor shape [*,8,1]) but the input received an input with 2 examples, each with shape [8,2] (tensor shape [2,8,2])
    at standardizeInputData (training.js:144:27)
    at LayersModel.standardizeUserDataXY (training.js:950:13)
    at LayersModel.<anonymous> (training.js:966:47)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at chunk-CCKAJO3Z.js?v=4267feed:85:61
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:1425:21)
    at __async (chunk-CCKAJO3Z.js?v=4267feed:69:10)
    at LayersModel.standardizeUserData (training.js:965:98)
    at LayersModel.<anonymous> (training.js:1225:49)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)

Also, how do you identify the time sequence values for the RNN model to use?

The errors you're encountering is shape mismatches between your data and the model's expectations.Here's breakdown of the issues In your issue ,the time sequence values are represented by the order of the notes within each melody (melody1 and melody2). The model learns the relationships between notes at different positions in the sequence to predict the next note.Orthogonal Initializer Warning: This warning is due to the default initializer being used for the weights of the LSTM layer. It's not an error, but it's suggesting that using the OI on a large matrix might result in slowness.
